# JetBrains rider IDE => Hosting Environment

Tags: c#, .net, webpack, configuration, rider

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P8ri.png)I am trying to move from Visual Studio 2022 to JetBrains rider with my .NET full-stack project.

I am using Webpack for my front-end side if it gives anyone a clue (I also run the Webpack command like in my vs2002).

The problem which occurs is the `HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopmentEnvironment` always returns false.

I tried to set it from the terminal with the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` command and in the configuration setting of debug mode of my project with no luck. I can't find any solution to this problem.

// different script for dev or prod

```
string scriptFileName = HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopmentEnvironment ? "/dist/app.entry.js" : "/dist/app.entry.min.js";
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ```
string scriptFileName = HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopmentEnvironment ? "/dist/app.entry.js" : "/dist/app.entry.min.js";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up two things: ASP.NET vs. ASP.NET Core. The environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is used by ASP.NET Core, whereas the method `HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopmentEnvironment` is only part of old ASP.NET.

As you already discovered, you have to set `DEV_ENVIRONMENT=1` and I see two options:

1. Set environment variable system-wide
2. Set environment variable within Rider configuration

## 1. System-wide

This implies that all consumers (your app, integration tests, etc.) use the same value, i. e. all apps are in development mode. It depends on your needs whether this is acceptable or not.

Assuming that you're working on Windows, you can either set the environment variable via GUI ([see here](https://www.aomeitech.com/windows-tips/set-windows-11-environment-variables.html)) or CLI ([see `setx` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx)).

Keep in mind that environment variables are picked up on application startup. So you have to restart Rider after changing the variable.

## 2. Rider

Open the *Run Configurations* and configure it like this:
[image]
You have to do this for all your Run Configurations.

Answer (score -1):

Add `DEV_ENVIRONMENT=1` to your project run configuration in your JetBrains IDE.

Comment: In what setting does this go in?